# Know the ObjectProperty of two subclasses using owlready

Tags: python, nlp, owl, rdflib, owlready

I built an ontology for units as follows:

Class: Unit -> Class: Temperature -> Classes: K, deg C, etc

Class: UnitTerms -> Classes: heat dissipation, storage temperature,...etc

- -> means subclass

ObjectProtery between classes is HasUnit, e.g. heat dissipation hasUnit Temperature

My question is how can I extract the relation(ObjectProperty) between two classes like the example below using python library(owlready2 or rdflib)?

Much appreciated for any hints/tips to solve that prob.
thanks

Comment: there is no object property "between" classes in OWL, or at least it's rather vague what exactly you mean

Comment: I mean how can I get determined that the ''heat dissipation'' class has object property "hasUnit" with ''deg C/K'' classes?

Comment: maybe I misunderstand you, but a class "has" no object properties ... can you please show the data? not in pseudo code. If your are talking about domain and range, those belong to the object properties, i.e. a property has a domain and a range. If you want to get all properties for a given domain (class) and range (class), then you can iterate those axioms and check if your given classes match

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.